# Responding to question with "act mature"

Tags: management, communication

I feel like my manager has been bullying me at work and I’m preparing to take action. He said something to me today I very much don’t understand. He told me to look at someone else’s code (who no longer works here) for an example, and when I asked if he knew which file in particular he told me to “act mature”. Why would asking which file an example is in be immature? I realize the reason probably is idiotic but I’m legitimately curious.

UPDATE: the manager meant a specific piece of code was the example. He wanted to launch a new process in a certain way and he knew another person had done this and told me to look at his code. Since this is one function in several files of code I thought I would ask if he knew which file it was in.

Comment: What tone of voice did you use when you asked which file?  He may have thought you were being cheeky and obstructive.  If there is already tension, you need to make _very_ sure that you use a neutral or friendly tone of voice. It's very easy to see something if you are looking for it, even it it's not there. Your manager may have expected an antagonistic response and filled in the gaps to interpret your question as such.

Comment: It was an angry tone. "He may have thought you were being cheeky and obstructive." sorry but can you explain how it could look this way?

Comment: If your boss has a staff member who he perceives to be disrespectful towards him, he could very well interpret an angry tone as, "I don't want to do this, so I'm going to make this as difficult as possible for you." An angry tone could easily reinforce that perception.

Comment: @JaneS I thought you had asked my managers tone of voice, he was angry. My tone was neutral.

Comment: Is he a non-technical type? Even if he is technical and he has no exposure to the code base, you are still annoying him with questions that he can't answer. Managers do get annoyed when they use hiring people as a silver bullet and they find out that the bullet they paid for is not 100% silver. Have you taken ANY time working out how the code base is organized? Have you located the documentation for the code base and have you learned to work with it?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan that's something. The project is relativley new and I'm the second person to work on it (the other person left before I began and didn't leave behind documentation). I've been working on a separate portion of the project so I've rarely had to look at the code left behind by the other person, so no I'm not familiar with it. I tried becoming familiar with it but with no documentation it wasn't easy.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan "Is he a non-technical type? " this is unclear to me. He says he's not a programmer and often tells me "that's your job" when I ask him questions or make suggestions. HOWEVER he also tells me which libraries to use and telling me how one script must use a system call to open a new one, that's technical in nature. Some of the technical requirements don't make sense or aren't possible but when I try to discuss with him he gets mad as "he's not technical".

Comment: If the tech requirements don't make sense or aren't possible, don't discuss. SAY that they don't make sense and why they don't make sense. Let him tell you why they make sense and how they make sense. What is it that he is a non-technical type that you don't get? What is it about being a total waste of time to ask technical questions to a non-technical type that you don't understand, unless that non-technical type can refer you to a technical type?

Comment: "If the tech requirements don't make sense or aren't possible, don't discuss. SAY that they don't make sense and why they don't make sense." what's the difference? For example how would I reword "we can't use library x because it's not compatible with the version of the language we're using" and he tells me to look at how the other person did it (though I think the other person didn't actually do it).

Comment: You look at what the other person did and you come back and say that the other person didn't do a damn thing. Even better, you say that you went over the functions in the library one more time and that there is no function that support what he is trying to get you to do and that the only alternative is for you to write your own function. If the library is  a commercial or Open Source library, start haunting the forums and ask questions.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have seen quite a few of those managers who know nothing but still want to feel like they are "contributing", so they will give you "guidance" as vaguely as possible, and nothing irritates them more than asking specific questions, because that causes their house of cards to come crashing down. I am sure if you observe carefully, you will realize that this manager often says nothing meaningful.

Comment: @MaskedMan he says less than nothing meaningful, he's telling me to use the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 4):

In isolation, "Do you happen to know which file it is in?" would seem to be a harmless question. If he knows, it would save you some time. If not, no harm done.

However, there seems to be some surrounding history in which you and your manager have not yet reached a meeting of minds on how to divide technical decision making between you. If he already felt you were leaning on him too much for technical ideas, asking about the file may have been the last straw.

One approach is to make sure you already have at least one option worked out before you discuss any technical issue with him.

Never ask "How can I do X?". Instead, present options analyzed in terms managers should care about, such as implementation time and implications for future development. He may be less likely to make his own proposals if you already have a plan, or are asking him to choose between plans based on their business consequences.

If, despite that, he adds another approach, tell him you will analyze it. Look into it. If it is not feasible tell him so, with reasons if he asks for them. If it is feasible, compare it to the approaches you are already considering, and see if it is at least as good.

Comment: To add a bit to Patricia's fine answer: always have at least two solutions available with a clear understanding of the trade offs - then when your manager (or co-worker) suggests something else you already have figured out for yourself which elements may or may not be important, and then solutions are argued based on developing common agreement of prioritizing the performance tradeoffs.

Comment: Why do you say "never ask how can I do x?"

Answer (score 3):

I would use the phrase "act more self-confident" if I were your boss.

He told you to *look at someone else’s code (who no longer works here) **for an example***. So, any code that was written by that person would qualify as an example. He did not mean any particular code file.

Your question that *if he knew which file in particular* made him feel that you don't have self confidence and cannot  work independently. That's probably why he said "act mature".

Your English sounds better than mine. I do not believe there was a language barrier. There could be some generation gap, though.

**Edit**

My answer would remain the same after the update of the question.

> Since this is one function in several files of code I thought I would ask if he knew which file it was in.

As far as I can tell, you are a technical employee (developer) and he is a manager. Finding which file is part of your job, not his. Again, I would do it myself without asking him first unless it takes me more than hours with no result. Then I would ask him. In other words, I would work more **confidently and independently** if I were you.

Comment: No no, he did mean a specific piece of code. I'll update the question.

Comment: @SomeCallMeSam I added my response to your update. My advice remains the same. Work more confidently and independently.

Comment: It seems you agree with my manager's action so maybe you can explain. Does it seem disrespectful to ask a manager which file he's talking about? He's from a different country so it could be a cultural thing. Why try to figure out what he's talking about instead of just asking?

Comment: Please do respond as I think I've seen this type of reasoning before but don't fully understand it. "Again, I would do it myself without asking him first unless it takes me more than hours with no result." why wait hours when you could ask him in 10 seconds? If he says he doesn't know then I agree it's my job to look it up, is it because in some cultures it's rude to put a manager in a position where he may say he doesn't know?

Comment: If the manager is the tech lead, he might have to tell you exactly which file you should look at. If he is a manager, why is it his job to figure out which file? If I were your manager (not the tech lead), I would be at least unhappy if you ask me which file because it's your job to figure it out.

Comment: To respond to your most recent comment, nobody would be happy if asked to do someone else's job **regardless of the culture**..

Comment: Asking if someone knows something isn't the same as asking them to do your job, especially when it's them who brought up the subject. It may be worth mentioning he's the only person I work with.

Comment: Actually the way you act is the same. "End of advice and end of discussion" that's the purpose of this site. I don't think you get it; if a question annoys someone it's not constructive to say "act mature", it would be constructive to say "I don't know the code base so I can't answer those types of questions".

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with both prior responses. They are very good responses. What I will add is you must really think and act independently. Software/Web development in less than large development teams is a team/solo profession. Its a team because there are organizational chains of command and expectations. At the same time it's a solo profession because we as developers are afforded a lot of flexibility and leeway in how we get things done.

Working with non-developer managers can have its drawbacks at times but it also affords us technical creativity as long as what we produce meets the business parameters set forth and works with the existing systems its meant to integrate with. Take advantage of that flexibility and use your initiative to learn. The best that can come out of it is you find the file or code you need on your own. The worse case is it took you a little digging but in the process you learned more about the inner workings of the application.

Comment: Tip: "do you happen to know offhand...? It'd save us some time if I don't have to go hunting" is a safer formulation; it emphasizes that you don't object to tracking it down, you're just looking to expedite the solution.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed , and the hard way, is that generally when your boss tells you to do XYZ then you should "let it sink in" before coming back for clarifications.

> He told me to look at someone else’s code (who no longer works here) for an example, and when I asked if he knew which file in particular he told me to “act mature”

When he told you to look at Bob's code, he was giving you an assignment. Now, surely you have questions and you *will* have follow-up questions. But at the current moment your boss is just giving you the general work-task.  If you had to look through three of Bob's files rather than the *exact* one-file is that a terrible punishment?

It is good to attempt to figure things out solo, for an hour, before coming back and asking questions. That way it's more of a "I'm stuck here , can you help?"

Context is everything though, not sure where you're coming from exactly  .

Finally, it's not a big deal. His "act mature" is not a huge insult really. We've seen far worse here.